# Qual a origem palavra composta "pão-de-ló"?

Tags: etimologia

Descrito como um bolo muito leve, feito de farinha de trigo, ovos e açúcar, qual seria a origem dessa denominação?  O que seria o "ló"?

Answer (score 2):

A etimologia de *pão de ló* é controversa, mas achei duas hipóteses:

1. O criador do pão de ló, alemão chamado Lot, deu o nome ao bolo: pão de Lot > pão de ló.
2. O substantivo *ló* pode se referir a um tecido fino, então, por comparação com a textura, diz-se *pão de ló*.

Fontes: https://www.dicio.com.br/pao-de-lo/ e https://origemdapalavra.com.br/pergunta/pao-de-lo/.

Comment: Você poderia adicionar as fontes?